# How to list paths for all dirs and subdirs only if they are under a certain size

Tags: bash

Two arrays obtained using:

`array1=($(ls -lad */ | awk '{print $5}'))`

`array2=($(ls -lad */ | awk '{print $9}'))`

Two array typsets:

`declare -a array1='([0]="4096" [1]="4096" [2]="4096" [3]="4096" [4]="4096" [5]="4096" [6]="4096" [7]="4096" [8]="4096")'`

`declare -a array2='([0]="bod/" [1]="working/" [2]="firm/" [3]="symbol/" [4]="info/" [5]="scripts/" [6]="development/" [7]="design/" [8]="testing/")'`

For the file sizes that are less than 10000 it will get the path for these directory names and create full path to be used in an `ls lRa` command where it lists the directories recursively where they directory size is less than 10000.

I currently have 8 file sizes for 8 directory names that are less than 10000 in size at the current level and instead of just printing the path for each directory name once it is doing 8 times. I assume its because I have configured my for loop wrong.

```
for s in ${!array1[*]} 
do
    if [ ${array1[$s]} -lt 10000 ]
    then 
        for dir in ${!array2[@]} 
        do
            paths=$(pwd {array2[$dir]}) 
            echo "$paths/${array2[$dir]}"
        done  
    else
        :
    fi 
done
```

**I HAVE EDITED MY QUESTION:**

I want to create a script that given a path i.e. `/a/path/to/use` it will call `ls -lRa` from this path.

However, the ls -lRa should only be called on directories and their sub-directories if their size is less than 10000 bytes.

For example, if `/a/path/to/use` contains 4 directories with sizes 4096,4096,12480,24620 it would only call ls -lRa on the first two with the last two being ignored.

Once the ls command has been called it will then do the same for any dirs in that directory and so on until it has inspected all dirs in the file structure from the original path.

Effectively it should list all the paths of all dirs less than the size of 10000 and ignore any that aren't (that includes a dir that is over 10000 but has some subdirs less than 10000, these should all be ignored). It should do so from the current directory I am in or if a dir path is specified then from that path down.

My attempt above does not appear to be working but provides some explanation as to what I am attempting.

Comment: Please edit your original question if you have additional content to add, do not make a new one

Comment: @SiegeX I replied to your answer informing you that your solution doesn't work and you haven't replied

Comment: Not much I can do with `it doesn't work`, find a site like pastebin.com and post output that "doesn't work".  Also, there are a lot of others on this site who may have different ways to solve this other than myself.

Comment: Well I didn't just write it doesn't work.. i have outlined what you solution is doing that it shouldn't be doing. Please refer to original question comments.. @SiegeX your solution goes through each directory twice one by one listing all directory paths twice and then on the second time it only lists each path once. It then proceeds to go through directories that have a size greater than 10000.

Comment: Why don't you just use `find */ -size -10000c`?

Comment: @lurker because that doesn't ignore directories over size 10000 ??

Comment: @bashprofile84 there are `find` options for that, too: `find */ -type f -size -10000c`. Just read the manual page for `find`.